# How to create a rule to send email to users of a role that belongs to a country?

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I'm using Profile2 module to assign a Country to a Role. For example I have:

- User1 | Role: "International Members" | Country: "UK"
- User2 | Role: "International Members" | Country: "Poland"
- User3 | Role: "International Members" | Country: "Japan"
- User4 | Role: "International Members" | Country: "US"

My content also has a field Country.

I have this **Rule**:

**Events**:

- After saving new content
- After updating existing content

**Conditions**:

- Content is published

**Actions**:

- Send mail to all users of a role (International Members)

That is sending email to all users in Role "International Members". 
I would like to:

1. Lookup the Country of the content
2. Send email to only those "International Members" whose profile Country matches the one of the content.

So If I publish a content with Country set as "US" it should only send an email to User4.

Any idea?

Comment: All I can think of is making a custom rules actions. let see if we can get something from contrib.

Comment: I think I could accomplish it easily by overwriting TO field in the Rule action "Send Email". But don't know which hook allows to do that.

Comment: that would be http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info_alter/7

Comment: Still need to lookup the Country of the content first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the action "fetch entity by property" and then use the country field and supply the country.

That will create a list to loop through so you can send mails.

Comment: Hey Niall, not to hijack your answer, but am I correct that you mean "Send a separated eMail to each of the selected users (so NOT just 1 eMail with in the 'to' all selected users)"? If my assumption is correct: can you think of any technique in rules actions to send only 1 eMail, but "to" multiple eMail IDs? Or do you think I should post that as a brand new question?

Comment: To be honest, I've never done too much with emails so I don't know but few sites would ever want multiple users in the to: of one email unless they were bcc'd. It's a breach of privacy if done wrong.

Comment: Merci Niall, never thought about that privacy issue, good point!

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you may want to give it a try to *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions:

- Load the VBO list that you want to be processed.
- Add a loop to perform a Rules Action, for each row contained in your Views results.

some more details about the VBO-view you'd have to create for this:

- It should include an appropriate filter of the Country.
- It should have exactly 1 result (row) for each user to be eMailed.
- One of the columns should be the eMail Id (I don't see other columns needed for this to work).

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".

Comment: Thanks for reply, ended up doing custom action for Rules. it just seemed easier to implement.

Comment: @KlaatuVerataNecto : merci beaucoup for sharing your own solution just now (via your extra answer)! I'd say "depends what you call ***easier***, but that's the beuty of Drupal of course. Though I must admit your own solution/answer is a great illustration of writing custom rules! so therefor also +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ended up doing custom **Action** for **Rules** module

[image]

```
function rulesemailsamecountry_rules_action_info() {
$actions = array(
    'rulesemailsamecountry_action_sendemailroleandcountry' => array(
        'label' => t('Send mail to all users of a role that match country node'),
        'group' => t('Custom'),
          'parameter' => array(
            'roles' => array(
              'type' => 'list<integer>',
              'label' => t('Roles'),
              'options list' => 'entity_metadata_user_roles',
              'description' => t('Select the roles whose users should receive the mail.'),
            ),
            'subject' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('Subject'),
              'description' => t("The mail's subject."),
            ),
            'message' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('Message'),
              'description' => t("The mail's message body."),
            ),
            'from' => array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => t('From'),
              'description' => t("The mail's from address. Leave it empty to use the site-wide configured address."),
              'optional' => TRUE,
            ),
          ),
      'base' => 'rules_action_mail_to_users_of_role_by_country',
      'access callback' => 'rules_system_integration_access', 
    ),        
);

return $actions;
}

function rules_action_mail_to_users_of_role_by_country($roles, $subject, $message, $from = NULL, $settings, RulesState $state, RulesPlugin $element) {

  $from = !empty($from) ? str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $from) : NULL;

  // All authenticated users, which is everybody.
  if (in_array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, $roles)) {
    $result = db_query('SELECT mail FROM {users} WHERE uid > 0');
  }
  else {
    $rids = implode(',', $roles);
    $country_code = $state->get('node')->value()->field_country['und'][0]['iso2'];    
    // Avoid sending emails to members of two or more target role groups.
    $query = "
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT u.mail 
    FROM {users} u 
    INNER JOIN {users_roles} r ON u.uid = r.uid
    INNER JOIN profile p ON p.uid = u.uid
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_profile_country c ON c.entity_id = p.pid
    WHERE r.rid IN ('".$rids."')
    AND c.field_profile_country_iso2 = '".$country_code."'";

    $result = db_query($query);    
  }

  // Now, actually send the mails.
  $params = array(
    'subject' => $subject,
    'message' => $message,
  );
  // Set a unique key for this mail.
  $name = isset($element->root()->name) ? $element->root()->name : 'unnamed';
  $key = 'rules_action_mail_to_users_of_role_' . $name . '_' . $element->elementId();  $languages = language_list();

  $message = array('result' => TRUE);
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $message = drupal_mail('rules', $key, $row->mail, language_default(), $params, $from);
    // If $message['result'] is FALSE, then it's likely that email sending is
    // failing at the moment, and we should just abort sending any more. If
    // however, $mesage['result'] is NULL, then it's likely that a module has
    // aborted sending this particular email to this particular user, and we
    // should just keep on sending emails to the other users.
    // For more information on the result value, see drupal_mail().
    if ($message['result'] === FALSE) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if ($message['result'] !== FALSE) {
    $role_names = array_intersect_key(user_roles(TRUE), array_flip($roles));
    watchdog('rules', 'Successfully sent email to the role(s) %roles.', array('%roles' => implode(', ', $role_names)));
  }
}
```